# autocomplete parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-services

I am currently using Jquery and a webservice to retrieve values for an autocomplete textbox. After the values are returned from the web service, I get an alert with "parser error" as the warning. Why is this?

```
Jquery

$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Service/WSDataService.asmx/GetStates",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data) {
            var datafromServer = data.d.split(":");
            $("[id$='txtautofromDB']").autocomplete({
                source: datafromServer
            });
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
}


web service
        [WebMethod]
        public string GetStates()
        {
            StringBuilder sbStates = new StringBuilder();
            List<string> stringlist = new List<String>();
            stringlist.Add("alabama");
            stringlist.Add("boston");
            stringlist.Add("abernathy");
            /*XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Data/States.xml"));*/
            try
            {
                foreach (string xnl in stringlist)
                {

                    sbStates.AppendFormat("{0}:", xnl);
                }

                sbStates = sbStates.Remove(sbStates.Length - 1, 1); //Removes the extra ":"
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string exp = ex.ToString();     //Setup a breakpoint here 
                //to verify any exceptions raised.
            }
            return sbStates.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How you have it now there is no reason to expect a JSon object.  Request just a generic string based response and it should work fine.

If you want to stick with the JSon object approach try returning a list of strings and then when it's deserialized into the JavaScript you'll have just that, a list of strings.

Update (How to get string via ajax):

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Service/WSDataService.asmx/GetStates",        
        success: function(data) {
            var datafromServer = data.split(":");
            $("[id$='txtautofromDB']").autocomplete({
                source: datafromServer
            });
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

Comment: so for the dataType: "json" section, how would I write it for a simple string or array of strings?

Comment: What happens if you go to /Service/WSDDataService.asmx/GetStates . Are you getting the expected output by physically going to the URL?

Comment: Yes, that returns the 3 states that should be there, and the code in the asmx file doesn't execute when I use it this way

Comment: Do you have any type of http handler intercepting service calls that could be re-routing your requests?  Taking a shot in the dark because the two main causes we've ruled out.

Answer (score 0):

Thats most likley because your response string isn't json parsable. Change the dataType parameter to this:

```
dataType : text
```

But why are you using POST to get some data? You should change that to GET

Comment: now I just get "error" when changing the dataType to text and changing POST to GET

Comment: If you change POST to GET you'll also have to change the service at /Service/WSDataService.asmx/GetStates.. maybe you should first try to change only the dataType to Text

Comment: Hmm sounds strange.. text shouldn't get parsed at all :( Maybe you can set up a jsfiddle with the echo ajax api (http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) to simulate your /Service/WSDataService.asmx/GetStates response. That would help me to take a look at it.